# extra space after apostrophe (quote mark) in Chrome brower

Tags: google-chrome

It is very weird that I have a extra space after apostrophe (quote mark) in Chrome (while don't in IE 10)

For example:  you'll becomes you'   ll
[image]

I am using Chrome Version 24.0.1312.57 m

Can anyone guide me to solve this problem?

Comment: can you post a pix?

Comment: thx. it is added

Comment: probably just a typo, but right click over that area and select "inspect element", and then open the div (probably a div) and check out the html code between the you + ll. It might be chance  "space" added by mistake... inside chrome

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem solved by changing the font type in the Chrome setting from "Microsoft Yahei" to "Arial". It should be a uni-code problem.